# how to enable a or disable a switch by check and unchecked a checkbox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo switch which is disabled by default:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="notifications-switch" aria-label="Notifications Switch" disabled="disabled" />
```

i have a check box,which is unchecked by default,i want to enabled the switch by checking the checkbox,here is the check box:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="eq1" class="k-checkbox">
```

here is what want but does not work,when i check it ,it does not enable the switch:

```
 $("#eq1").change(function () {
          if (this.checked) {
              $("#notifications-switch").is(":disabled") = false;
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in kendo in order to achieve the enable disable the follwoing should be use(regarding my question):

```
 $("#notifications-switch").data("kendoMobileSwitch").enable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:you need to use `prop` to disable the switch. you can use `:checked` value to make it disable or enabled

```
$("#eq1").change(function () {
     $("#notifications-switch").prop("disabled",!$(this).is(":checked"));
  });
```

Comment: when its a check box it works but when its a switch not,if you add    $(function () {
          $("#notifications-switch").kendoMobileSwitch();    
      });

Comment: you need to check in kendoMobileSwitch API documentation for disabling switch. I tried to google but looks like it does not support

Comment: if i dont want to use kendo,is there such a thing in jquery?